# When I add to arrayList, it is adding the main notes list not the objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Person object that has been initialized and if I call the method like getName I can retrieve them.

```
public Person( String fName, String lName, List<Role> roleList) {
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.roleList = new ArrayList<Role>();
}
```

Each Person needs to have a list of roles so I have a list called `roleList` which I initialize using `List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList();`

when created it is passed as

```
testDriver = new Person("Mike", "Joy", testRoleList);
testDriver2 = new Person("Rich", "Johns", testRoleList);
```

In my calling class i want to add an item only to that staff members `testRoleList`. For this test i have made `testRoleList` public but I do have a getter which retrieves the `testRoleList`;

```
Role roleToAdd = Role.DRIVER;

// Only add the new role to the test driver
testDriver.testRoleList.add(roleToAdd);
```

But when you run this it does add the role, but if I try to retrieve the size of the testDriver and testDriver2 list using:

```
System.out.println(testDriver.testRoleList.size());

System.out.println(testDriver2.testRoleList.size());
```

The resulting list size is 1 for both list even though I haven't added a role to the testDriver2.

How can I just add the role to just testDriver or Just testDriver2

Comment: As we haven't the complex code (testDriver is a Person object that didn't have a testRoleList but a roleList property) I'm pretty sure it's just a bug in the code ...

Comment: It's actually not a problem of call-by-value vs. call-by-reference. The problem seems to be somewhere in the `Person` class, e.g. `roleList` being static or sth. like that. Also you're initializing `roleList` in the constructor but add the element to `testRoleList` which might just be a totally different (and shared) list.

Comment: I have tried it now by saying in the Person constructor this.testRoleList = roleList which is the parameter it is passed as its created. but i still get the same list size it seems to be adding only to testRoleList and not the property of it inside the specific person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that whenever you create a new `Person`, the passed `List` will be overwritten with a freshly created new empty `List`.
So if you add something to the list, for example by:

```
testDriver.testRoleList.add(roleToAdd);
```

And after that create a new `Person`:

```
testDriver2 = new Person("Rich", "Johns", testRoleList);
```

Then the list will be empty again, because you have this code in the constructor:

```
this.roleList = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

You need exactly to know what your code does, change it so it does what you want. At this point it may be good to say that it is not a good design to `change` passed parameters by overriding them.
If you want something like a global `List` of roles, then it is not the task of the class `Person` to initialize this `List`. Let some other class do this job, pass the reference to the list to `Person` as you already do and then do not override it with a new reference. Save it, use it, add something, but not recreate it.

But if you want every `Person` to have its own `List` of roles, then there is no need to pass a reference from outside. In this scenario it is the task of the class `Person` and only of this class to manage such a `List`.
In this case you should remove the `List parameter` from the constructor but create a `List` as member variable, then offer some methods to interact with it. Here's an example:

```
public final class Person {

    private final List<Role> mRoleList;

    public Person(final String fName, final String lName) {
        ...
        mRoleList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void addRole(final Role role) {
        mRoleList.add(role);
    }

    public boolean hasRole(final Role role) {
        return mRoleList.contains(role);
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(mRoleList);
    }

}
```

Then you can do such stuff:

```
Role r1 = ...
Role r2 = ...

Person person1 = new Person("a", "a");
Person person2 = new Person("b", "b");

person1.addRole(r1);
person1.addRole(r2);

person2.addRole(r2);
```

And the result is what you would expect, `person1` has `r1` and `r2`, `person2` only has `r2`.
As side note, maybe a `Set` instead of a `List` reflects better what you want your `roleList` to be. Queries like `contain` then are very fast (`O(1)`), in a `List` they are very slow (`O(n)`).

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, you are referring same object `testRoleList`, in both of your objects `testDriver`, `testDriver2`.

When constructing the `Person` object, pass List of Roles by constructing different List holding `Role` for each `Person` object.

Set is better than a List from performance point of view.

If Roles are limited and well decided, you could use `EnumSet` in place of `ArrayList`. Here also, you need to initialize different EnumSet "Role" objects for different Person objects.

To avoid Synchronization issues, use `Collections.synchronizedSet`.

```
Set<MyEnum> s = Collections.synchronizedSet(EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnum.class));
```

Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html